# Remove Bootstrap validation errors

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using [Boostrap validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) for my form. I have a checkbox that enable two textboxes when it unchecked, and disable them when it checked.
I want that any validation message that related to these two textboxes will be removed once the textboxes has been switched to disable mode.

Is that possible?

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade"  id="myReport" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myReportLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="width:300px;top:150px;left:100px">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myReportLabel">My Report</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form  data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="myReport">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="myReportLabel">Select a range for the report</h5>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="key"/>
        <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="all" checked> All
    </label>
  </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="from" class="control-label">From:</label>
             <div class="controls">
                <input type="number" disabled required required name="from" placeholder="" id="fromAnomali" class="form-control">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="to" class="control-label">To:</label>
             <div class="controls">
                <input type="number" disabled  required required name="to"  placeholder="" id="to" class="form-control"/>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="minSize" class="control-label">Minimum size:</label>
             <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" required name="minSize" value="4"  min="4" id="minSize" class="form-control"/>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sendBtnclusteringReport">Get Report</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#all").bind("click",function(){
   $("#from,#to").prop('disabled', $(this).prop('checked'));
})

$().ready(function(){
    $('#myReport').validator();
});
```